Independence of Random Variables $Z_1=\min\{N_1,p\}$ and $Z_2=\min\{N_2,p\}$.
Suppose that $N$ particles (a fixed quantity) are randomly distributed in the interval $[0,1]$ and the particles are independently coming from the uniform distribution in $[0,1]$. Now consider any two non-intersecting subintervals of $[0,1]$ and $N_1$, $N_2$ be the number of particles in those subintervals. Now let us consider the random variables $Z_1=\min\{N_1,p\}$ and $Z_2=\min\{N_2,p\}$, where $p$ is a constant.
Now, I am trying to say something about the independence of $Z_1$ and $Z_2$.
I am confused how to do so!

Well, $N_1+N_2≤N$, right?   So, at least there are edge cases in which the variables are dependent.

Yeah, I was also expecting them to be dependent. Can you give any idea about their dependency?

Well, I gave one example (take $p>N$ just to get it off the table).  Similarly, knowing that, say, $N_1=0$ would be evidence that $N_2$ was larger than you'd expect otherwise (since we'd know that the $N$ points were chosen uniformly from a smaller region that we thought initially).

But the case I am interested in is that $N$ is very large, and $p$ is very small compared to N. You can assume that $p=10$.

Well, in that case the dependence will be weak, of course.  Presumably you'll just get $p$ for each value and that won't tell you much.

Actually, I want to compute Cov$(Z_1, Z_2)$, and I don't have the joint distribution. That is why I was trying to check their independence.

The problem needs to specify if $N$ is random or not, and more clarity on how the particles are placed (such as independence assumptions). As is, it is not clear if this is supposed to be a Poisson point process or not.

Suppose the two intervals have lengths $L_1$ and $L_2$, both $>0$, $N \ge 1$, and $p \ge 1$.
Then $\mathbb P(Z_1 = 0) = \mathbb P(N_1 = 0) = (1 - L_1)^N$, $\mathbb P(Z_2 = 0) = \mathbb P(N_2 = 0) = (1-L_2)^N$,
and $$\mathbb P(Z_1 = 0, Z_2 = 0) = \mathbb P(N_1 = 0, N_2 = 0) = (1-L_1-L_2)^N \ne \mathbb P(Z_1 = 0) \mathbb P(Z_2 = 0)$$
so they are dependent.
[EDIT] More generally, assume  $i, j < p$ and $i + j \le N$.
$$\eqalign{\mathbb P(Z_1 = i) = \mathbb P(N_1 = i) &= {N \choose i} L_1^i (1-L_1)^{N-i}\cr
\mathbb P(Z_2 = j) = \mathbb P(N_2 = j) &=  {N \choose j} L_2^j (1-L_2)^{N-j}\cr \mathbb P(Z_1 = i, Z_2 = j) = 
\mathbb P(N_1 = i, N_2 = j) &= \frac{N!}{i!j! (N-i-j)!} L_1^i L_2^j (1-L_1 - L_2)^{N-i-j} \cr}$$

How can we calculate the general case $\mathbb P(Z_1 = i, Z_2 = j) $?

Thank You, but you have not considered the case when either of them is equal to $p$ or both.

$\mathbb P(Z_1 = p, Z_2 = j) = 1 - \sum_{i=0}^{p-1} \mathbb P(Z_1 = i, Z_2 = j)$ etc.
